# Do I need a comma in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas

> When scanning in one position for longer time period a slight movement
>   can occur in the scanner position due to changes in temperature.

Am I missing a comma in this sentence?

Comment: A comma is not necessary. But as @queeg pointed out, an *a* before longer would be expected; either that or make *period* plural. Also, watch out for those people who insist *due to* is "substandard" here and should be replaced by *because of.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are missing a comma after period.

When is a conjunction in the sentence.  If the when-clause comes before the main clause, we use a comma.

"When scanning in a position for a longer time period, a slight movement......".

Comment: You also, most probably, need to place an additional 'a' after 'for' but before 'longer'. 'one position for a longer time period, a slight' etc.

Comment: A comma is not necessary, but some might find one useful.